# Is their Any Error boundary in web components

Tags: web-component, babel-polyfill, lit-element, lit-html

Is their anything in web components (lit-html) like error boundary in React.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something equivalent, I've stumbled upon Salesforce's LWC `errorCallback()`: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_error

Looking briefly at the implementation, it requires cooperation from the throwing component and the error boundary: the component will have its own methods catching exceptions, then walking up the DOM tree until it finds an error boundary (which it identifies as a LWC component –this itself is done through a field with a known `Symbol`– with a defined `errorCallback()` method); so it will only works between two LWC components.

To make it work across component frameworks, I suppose one could dispatch an `ErrorEvent` from a component (this still requires components to handle their errors to dispatch that event) and have it bubble the DOM tree up to the error boundary component which would handle it (and `stopPropagation()`).